# Toggle accordion using button and if open, keep it open

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

My scope looks something like this

```
$scope.audit = [{
    "specification": "Test1",
    "username":"user1",
    "lastname":"lastname1"
},
{
    "specification": "Test1",
    "username":"user2",
    "lastname":"lastname2"
},
{
    "specification": "Test2",
    "username":"user1",
    "lastname":"lastname1"
},
{
    "specification": "Test2",
    "username":"user2"
    "lastname":"lastname2"
}]
```

I `groupBy` specification and have two buttons as filters, `username` and `lastname`, which can be clicked to filter the data. The specification and the filters are part of accordion heading.

Now when I click on specification heading, the panel opens up well. But how do I open an accordion using filter buttons? And if the panel is open, how can I keep it open and not toggle the data?

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-width: 1600px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;">
    <accordion close-others=false> 
        <accordion-group is-open="open" data-ng-repeat="(spec,value) in audit | orderBy: 'specification' | groupBy: 'specification'"> 
            <accordion-heading>
                <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !open}"></i> 
                <b>{{spec}}</b>

                <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();" >
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right" > 
                        <button data-style="slide-right" ng-click="Activate(this,'username')" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">
                            <i title="Filter" class="fa fa-filter" style="color:#006b24"></i>
                            Username
                        </button>               
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group pull-right" > 
                        <button data-style="slide-right" ng-click="Activate(this,'lastname')" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">
                            <i title="Filter" class="fa fa-filter" style="color:#006b24"></i>
                            Lastname
                        </button>               
                    </div>
                </div>  
            <accordion-heading> 

            <div data-ng-repeat="val in value">
                {{val.username}} -- {{val.lastname}}
            </div>
        <accordion-group>   
    <accordion>
</div>
```

With my current approach on clicking the `Activate()`, I set the value of `open` to true, but this opens up all the accordions.

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.Activate = function(val,filter) {
    if (!$scope.open) {
        $scope.open = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that you're missing a comma when declaring `specification` property in your object `audit`. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that was just a typo. I have updated the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

HTML Code

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-width: 1600px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden;">
    <accordion close-others=false>
        <accordion-group is-open="open" data-ng-repeat="(spec,value) in audit | groupBy:'specification'">
            <accordion-heading class="col-lg-12">
                <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': open[$index], 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !open[$index]}"></i>
                <b ng-click="Activate($index)">{{spec}}</b>
                <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();">
                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <button data-style="slide-right" ng-click="Activate($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">
                            <i title="Filter" class="fa fa-filter" style="color:#006b24"></i>
                            Username
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                        <button data-style="slide-right" ng-click="Activate($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-xs">
                            <i title="Filter" class="fa fa-filter" style="color:#006b24"></i>
                            Lastname
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </accordion-heading>
            <div ng-show="open[$index]" ng-hide="!open[$index]">
                <span class="col-lg-12" data-ng-repeat="val in value">{{val.username}} -- {{val.lastname}}</span>
            </div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.open = [];
$scope.Activate = function (ind) {

    if (!$scope.open[ind]) {
        $scope.open[ind] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.open[ind] = false;
    }
}
```